# What is model-level query in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I read some books and articles but I din't understand what it want to say?
where and when should I use model-level query?

> If you’re using model-level query filters (see section 3.5.1), the SQL
>   you can write has limitations—for instance, ORDER BY won’t work. The way
>   around this problem is to apply the IgnoreQueryFilters method before the
>   FromSql command and re-create the model-level query filter in your SQL code.

Comment: There is no "model-level query". The term is [model-level query **filter**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#model-level-query-filters), i.e. filter of the query configured at model-level.

Comment: What is the book for this statement? Are the content the same as the doc from @lvan? For `EF Core Model-level query`, it could work with order by. Not sure what your statement it did not work with order by.

Comment: @TaoZhou,name of that book is Entity Framework Core In Action.

Comment: @Behnam Which paragrah? You may consider sharing us more content for `model-level query filters`. I have never read this book. You may try the code in the book, and see whether there is any unexpected result.

Comment: @TaoZhou,Section 3.5.1,Page 83,Using a soft delete—using model-level query filters to “hide” entities.

Comment: Did not see this conent from [3.5.1 Using a soft delete—using model-level query filters to “hide” entities](https://livebook.manning.com#!/book/entity-framework-core-in-action/chapter-3/point-4445-220-220-0). You could try to make a test with this code.

Answer (score -1):

It is a clear term. Querying at model level. For exmaple

```
var students = context.Students.Where(s=> s.Id = 1);
```

This generates the following sql query: `Select * from students where id =1`